# Evaluate the limit of the form $\infty \cdot 0$ without series.

Tags: limits

I Want to show that :
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left[\left(\frac{x}{x+1} \right)^x - \frac{1}{e} \right]=\frac{1}{2e}
$$
With the substitution $x+1=t$ and the known limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left( 1+\frac{a}{x} \right)^x=e^a
$$
we see that
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+1} \right)^x =\frac{1}{e}
$$
so the starting limit  has the form $\infty \cdot 0$.

We can solve this form  using the series expansion at infinity:
$$
\left( \frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2ex}+O\left( \frac{1}{x^2}\right)
$$
 I think that there is some ''trick'' to evaluate this limit also for students that does not know this Laurent series,  but I don't see it. 
Someone has a suggestion?

Comment: What is known about logarithms and the exponential function?

Comment: The definitions and principal properties of exp and log functions and the limit to $\infty$ of $\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$.

Comment: Which definition of $\exp$? The power series? Or the one as the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$?

Comment: We can suppose that both can be used.

Comment: Then $\bigl(\frac{x}{x+1}\bigr)^x = \bigl(1 + \frac{1}{x}\bigr)^{-x} = \exp \bigl(-x\log \bigl(1+\frac{1}{x}\bigr)\bigr)$ might be accessible.

Comment: Of course one could also try whether L'Hospital isn't too ugly.

Comment: @DanielFischer: My problem is not the limit of  $\left( \frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x$. I've added something to my question.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. You get the limit you want if you use the second order Taylor expansion of $\exp$ and $y \mapsto \log (1+y)$ about $0$. That is, however, probably not what you're looking for. If the students know L'Hospital's rule, applying it to $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\bigl(\frac{x}{x+1}\bigr)^x - e^{-1}}{\frac{1}{x}}$$ may be another way to find the limit. Personally, I find the Taylor expansion much more appealing.